# Nested ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat='employee in filteredStaff ' ng-click="describeEmployee(employee)" >
    <div class="gridNameTd">
        <div ng-click="addTeamMember(employee)">{{getEmployeeByName(employee.name).name}} </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

That is part of my code. Both of 'ng-click' are called. I need only internal ng-click="addTeamMember(employee).
How to handle it?

Comment: You might also want to look into a filter for handling the employee name. Granted I don't know what your function is doing, but getEmployeeByName(employee.name).name looks like you have an employee's name already, and you're just translating it into some other version of the name. So potentially this could change to {{ employee.name | employeeName }} where employeeName is the new filter that does whatever getEmployeeByName() was doing previously. This would allow better re-use of that function vs having to inject it into your controller scope all the time (assuming it's used elsewhere)

Answer (score 6):

You need to have the event not bubble up through the DOM tree. On your click even you can pass in the event and tell it to not pass it up the chain with `$event.stopPropagation`

Here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OjiFIjCEQ7jDG2owm33D?p=preview

Example:

In your controller:

```
$scope.addTeamMember = function($event, employee) {
  $event.stopPropagation();
  // do stuff....
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='employee in filteredStaff ' ng-click="describeEmployee(employee)" >
  <div class="gridNameTd">
    <div ng-click="addTeamMember($event, employee)">{{getEmployeeByName(employee.name).name}} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not find where to get $event. Did  :<div ng-click="addTeamMember(employee); $event.stopPropagation();">{{getEmployeeByName(employee.name).name}}</div>

Comment: One sec. Transitioned from phone to PC so I could properly build out a sample. :)

Comment: Edited the sample to show the HTML changes and provided a link to a plunker sample.

Comment: Yes - thx. I got it : I need to send $event from HTML element. And $event is a part of JQuery

Comment: JQuery lite is bundled into Angular. You'll find a number of similarities (because it is JQuery ;) )

Answer (score 0):

umm if i understand your question you need this?

```
<div ng-repeat='employee in filteredStaff'>
    <div class="gridNameTd">
        <div ng-click="addTeamMember(employee)">{{getEmployeeByName(employee.name).name}} </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the propagation of the inner events using `$event.stopPropagation()` as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat='employee in filteredStaff ' ng-click="describeEmployee(employee)" >
    <div class="gridNameTd">
        <div ng-click="addTeamMember(employee); $event.stopPropagation()">{{getEmployeeByName(employee.name).name}} </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```